# How to drag list view item along with image in android

Tags: android, listview, gridview, drag-and-drop

In my application I want to drag list item. In my list item I have text view and image. So for that I followed the bellow url

https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView

By using this sample, I changed my text view  and image view then displayed my data. And drag and drop also working fine. But the issue is image will not change. But the image is moving along with text. So my point is after dropping the item text is changed image wont changed. So how to change image also.

This is the my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DragListView mDragListView;
    private ArrayList<Pair<Long, String>> mItemArray;
    private ArrayList arrayList_data = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList arrayList_images = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrayList_data.add("Dashboard");
        arrayList_data.add("Evaluations");
        arrayList_data.add("Inventory");
        arrayList_data.add("Buy Leads");
        arrayList_data.add("Insurance");
        arrayList_data.add("Cartrade Price");
        arrayList_data.add("RTO Check");
        arrayList_data.add("Market Place");
        arrayList_data.add("Auctions");
        arrayList_data.add("Integrator Report");
        arrayList_data.add("What's New");

        arrayList_images.add(R.mipmap.menu_dashboard);
        arrayList_images.add(R.mipmap.menu_evaluations);
        arrayList_images.add(R.mipmap.menu_inventory);
        arrayList_images.add(R.mipmap.menu_buyleads);
        arrayList_images.add(R.mipmap.menu_insurance);
        arrayList_images.add(R.mipmap.menu_cartradeprice);
        arrayList_images.add(R.mipmap.menu_rtocheck);
        arrayList_images.add(R.mipmap.menu_marketplace);
        arrayList_images.add(R.mipmap.menu_acuttions);
        arrayList_images.add(R.mipmap.menu_integrator);
        arrayList_images.add(R.mipmap.whatsnew);

        mDragListView = (DragListView) findViewById(R.id.drag_list_view);

        mDragListView.setDragListListener(new DragListView.DragListListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onItemDragStarted(int position) {
//                mRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(mDragListView.getContext(), "Start - position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemDragEnded(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
//                mRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                if (fromPosition != toPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(mDragListView.getContext(), "End - position: " + toPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        mItemArray = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList_data.size(); i++) {
            mItemArray.add(new Pair<>((long) i, arrayList_data.get(i).toString()));
        }

//        setupListRecyclerView();
        setupGridVerticalRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setupListRecyclerView() {
        mDragListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        ItemAdapter listAdapter = new ItemAdapter(mItemArray, arrayList_images, R.layout.list_item, R.id.image, false);
        mDragListView.setAdapter(listAdapter, true);
        mDragListView.setCanDragHorizontally(false);
        mDragListView.setCustomDragItem(new MyDragItem(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item));
    }

    private void setupGridVerticalRecyclerView() {
        mDragListView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 3));
        ItemAdapter listAdapter = new ItemAdapter(mItemArray, arrayList_images, R.layout.grid_item, R.id.item_layout, true);
        mDragListView.setAdapter(listAdapter, true);
        mDragListView.setCanDragHorizontally(true);
        mDragListView.setCustomDragItem(null);

    }

    private static class MyDragItem extends DragItem {

        MyDragItem(Context context, int layoutId) {
            super(context, layoutId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindDragView(View clickedView, View dragView) {
            CharSequence text = ((TextView) clickedView.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText();
            ((TextView) dragView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);
            ImageView image = ((ImageView) clickedView.findViewById(R.id.image));
            ((ImageView) dragView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageDrawable(image.getDrawable());
            dragView.findViewById(R.id.item_layout).setBackgroundColor(dragView.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_item_background));
        }
    }
}
```

This is adapter class

```
class ItemAdapter extends DragItemAdapter<Pair<Long, String>, ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private int mLayoutId;
    private int mGrabHandleId;
    private boolean mDragOnLongPress;
    ArrayList<Integer> arl_images;

    ItemAdapter(ArrayList<Pair<Long, String>> list, ArrayList<Integer> arl_images, int layoutId, int grabHandleId, boolean dragOnLongPress) {
        mLayoutId = layoutId;
        mGrabHandleId = grabHandleId;
        mDragOnLongPress = dragOnLongPress;
        setHasStableIds(true);
        setItemList(list,arl_images);
        this.arl_images = arl_images;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(mLayoutId, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
        String text = mItemList.get(position).second;
        holder.mText.setText(text);
        holder.image.setImageResource(arl_images.get(position));
        holder.itemView.setTag(mItemList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mItemList.get(position).first;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends DragItemAdapter.ViewHolder {
        TextView mText;
        ImageView image;

        ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView, mGrabHandleId, mDragOnLongPress);
            mText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClicked(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Item long clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update function `public void swapItems(int pos1, int pos2)`in `DragItemAdapter.java` with arl_images list swap code.

```
  public void swapItems(int pos1, int pos2) {
        ......
            Collections.swap(mItemList, pos1, pos2);
            Collections.swap(mArl_imagesList, pos1, pos2);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
       ......
    }
```

update `ItemAdapter.java` too

```
 @Override 
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
        String text = mItemList.get(position);
        holder.mText.setText(text);
        holder.image.setImageResource(mArl_imagesList.get(position).second);//mArl_imagesList from DragItemAdapter
        holder.itemView.setTag(mItemList.get(position));
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. but it is not working

Comment: no..finally got it for changing this method too...     public void changeItemPosition(int fromPos, int toPos) {
        if (mItemList != null && mItemList.size() > fromPos && mItemList.size() > toPos) {
            T item = mItemList.remove(fromPos);
            Integer item_int = arl_images.remove(fromPos);
            mItemList.add(toPos, item);
            arl_images.add(toPos, item_int);
            notifyItemMoved(fromPos, toPos);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use draglistview library :
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4036

Comment: yes, i am using same library..it is working fine, but image will not be changed. I don,t know where to change code

Comment: you are using holder? then remove it